# Microsoft SQL int type take not negative value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem. I created a table in Microsoft SQL and I would like one column to take not negative values. For example, EmployeeSalary column type is int and it hasn't a negative value.

Comment: Use a [`CONSTRAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189862(v=sql.105)).

Comment: ...or a trigger to raise errors (but I agree that constraint is better here)

Comment: Are you sure you want to add this constraint? One never thought interest rates could go negative, but they did ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution of your problem:

Use `CHECK` while creating Table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_name
(
    col1 int CHECK (col1 >= 0)
)
```

**OR**

If you want to make a column to reject negative number, after creating the table then you can do like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK (col_name >= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set condition when creating the table try:

```
EmployeeSalary money CHECK (EmployeeSalary>= 0)
```

If you just want to check during some script execution you can use if :

```
if(@Var > 0) begin

....

end
```

Comment: You can't use `IF` in a query, nor should you. That's what the `WHERE` clause is for

Answer (score 0):

go tools>options>designer

"prevent changes that require table re-creation" this one should be unchecked.